# Web API reserved words?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, controller

"Reserved" words may not be the best term here, but is there anything that would prevent me from naming a Web API Controller *DocumentationController*? Oddly enough, the issue only happens when running in Visual Studio (2012). If I publish to a local IIS site it works fine.

The problem is trying to hit the default `Get()` method on my `DocumentationController`, which for testing purposes looks like this:

```
// GET api/documentation
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
   return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "success");
}
```

When running in Visual Studio this will return a 302 "object moved" error, an then subsequently a 404. But if I rename the controller to `DocumentationTest` or `Docs` it works just fine in VS and my local IIS site.

I've also tried having this method simply return a `string` but that didn't make a difference.

**Is there a reason I cannot (or shouldn't) name my controller "DocumentationController"?**

[**This answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669244/routing-reserved-words-in-asp-net) (for ASP.NET MVC, at least) says that the only reserved words are "controller", "action", and "area".

**SOLUTION:**

There ended up being a folder in the Web API project called *Documentation*. This, for some reason, wouldn't work when debugging in VS, but worked fine on IIS. I am just going to rename that folder.

Comment: When I google DocumentationController about the only thing I see is a NuGet package for WebApi.DocumentationController.  Are you using that by any chance?

Comment: `302` is usually used for redirecting, where does you get redirected?

Comment: @Dave I'll check into that nuget package. I don't believe I'm using it but I'll verify.

Comment: @Mathew when I navigate to api/documentation that returns the 302 and then I am redirected to api/documentation/ (with the trailing forward slash).

Comment: That's insane. Are you sure there are no folders or files with that name in the root? Did you tried creating such a controller in a blank new project just to see if it works?

Comment: Ugh. Yes that was the problem. There was another folder called Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ended up being a folder in the Web API project called Documentation. It had been excluded from the project file so it wasn't visible in Visual Studio and I didn't notice it right away. This, for some reason, wouldn't work when debugging in Visual Studio (the folder still existed locally), but worked fine on IIS. I am just going to rename this folder so it doesn't conflict with any of my controllers.

Answer (score 1):

DocumentationController is not a reserve word, and the error "302 object moved" isn't an error indicating that a reserve word has been used.  (I don't think your solution would compile if you were using a reserve word)  I suggest looking into the possibility that WebApi.DocumentationController has another reference somewhere in  your solution.